# Excel VBA activate window without file name yet, cause from xltm template

Tags: excel, vba, templates, window, activation

I want to use an Excel template XLTM. I want to insert some information that I copied from another Excel file. 
Opening the other file and copying the information is easy, but then re-activating the first Excel document is where I have trouble.

If I store the template as xlsm, I can use that filename in the macro and it works fine. But I would like to use an XLTM, in order that people wouldn't accidentally overwrite the template.

Therefore at the moment of returning to the file, it's not yet saved and has therefore no definite file name. 
Is there a way to re-activate the window that is based on my xlmt file?

Below macro works fine, as long as my template is *Template.xlsm*. But I would like to use an actualy xltm file as a template.
Is this even possible?

```
Sub Update()
'
' Kampagnen Updaten
'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "M:\Client\0001Jobs\2018\V11857Test\Special_campaigns.xlsx" _
        , UpdateLinks:=0
    Range("A3:A90").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Dropdown").Visible = True
    Sheets("Dropdown").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E1").Select
    Sheets("Dropdown").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Sheets("Template").Select

    Windows("Special_campaigns.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```